# Vuejs router cant reach any components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I might be using some outdated guide and this might be the result of it, new to Vuejs.
My **App.vue**:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img src="../assets/logo.png">
      <router-view/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App'
}
</script>

<style>
  #app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
  }
</style>
```

My **main.js**:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { App } from './app'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

**router/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import { routes } from '../app'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: routes
})
```

And then comes the **app/routes.js**

```
import accounts from './accounts'
import budgets from './budgets'
import transactions from './transactions'

export default [...accounts, ...budgets, ...transactions]
```

Finally, **app/accounts/routes.js**

```
import * as components from './components'

export default [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: components.AccountsListView,
    name: 'accountsListView' 
  },
  {
    path: '/accounts/create',
    component: components.CreateEditAccounts,
    name: 'createAccounts'
  },
  {
    path: '/accounts/edit',
    component: componenets.CreateEditAccounts,
    name: 'editAccounts'
  }
]
```

For some reason I can’t hit any of my components, for example if I go to `localhost:8080/accounts/create` then I end up on index page with the changed url instead of hitting the corresponding component. Is there anything obviously wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: Browsers have this tool for developers ... called developer tools console ... have you checked yours for errors? nevermind, this is a server side issue, right?

Comment: Console is clean of any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this export

```
export default [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: components.AccountsListView,
    name: 'accountsListView' 
  },
  {
    path: '/accounts/create',
    component: components.CreateEditAccounts,
    name: 'createAccounts'
  },
  {
    path: '/accounts/edit',
    component: componenets.CreateEditAccounts,
    name: 'editAccounts'
  }
]
```

Since the routes array is the default export, you would need to use this import.
The object style import is applicable where there are multiple exports.

```
import routes from '../app'
```

Ref: [MDN web docs - export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Comment: I've update the question a little, seems like code editor on SO has eaten the first line of the routes.js, which was `import * as components from './components'`. Should i put your import at the top of app/accounts/routes.js ?

Comment: No, that's the amended import for **app/routes.js**.

Comment: Oh wait - confusion - **router/index.js** and **app/routes.js** seem to be the same. In any case, the import of your routes array should not have curly brackets.

Comment: fixed the question

Comment: Ok, cool. Just change the import in **router/index.js**, as the default export from **app/routes.js** is still an array. (BTW perhaps should be `import routes from '../app/routes'`)

Comment: Done, no errors in console but still can't reach anything else than index with urls like `localhost:8080/accounts/create`, `localhost:8080/accounts/`

Comment: Bad luck. Perhaps do a console.log in **router/index.js** to see what routes are. (Actually that might be difficult)

Comment: In **router/index.js** did you import `from '../app/routes'` or still `from '../app'`?

Comment: `from '../app/routes'` as other option was throwing an error

Comment: Try logging all the bits in **app/routes.js**

Comment: Done, seems like it can't find things like **app/accounts/routes.js** and doesn't throw any error, i've put a console.log in app/routes and all routes are "nothing", console.log in **app/accounts/routes.js** didn't get called at all

Comment: Oh yeah, `import accounts from './accounts/routes'`.

Answer (score 1):

**main.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { App } from './app'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Maybe you are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available.

Edit#1

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="App">
      <router-view />
  </div>
</template>
```

Then maybe you haven't include `router-view` in your `App` component.

Comment: Still the same issue. I guess i'm using the "correct" version as i can see my App.vue

Comment: Then I suspect you haven't include router-view in your App component.

Comment: My bad that i didn't mention it, but it's there

Comment: Okay. Then it seems like its the import error as @Richard Matsen points out